# Less network calls for getting offsets of a Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-rest

This is the API call for getting topic offsets -

```
GET /topics/(string:topic_name)/partitions/(int:partition_id)/offsets
```

Here we have to give partition_id.

Is there a way to get offsets for all partitions of a topic in one API call?

Comment: Are you required to use a REST API? You can get the group offsets for a topic using a plain consumer instance.

Comment: Yes I m required to use REST API, though I won't have access to Kafka Admin APIs. That's a point but sadly, I won't be able to use consumer instance, consuming records is part of another application, that I won't be touching.

Comment: In that case, I don't think you can get all partition offsets at once